# how to get the multiple selected values in 2nd dropdown

Tags: php

i am new in php coding.i am facing a problem.i have a drop down list where user can select multiple values.Like i have a drop down list of different writers.suppose user select two or more writers from the first drop down list.In 2nd drop down list should show all the books of the both the writer.All the values(writers and books) are coming from database.Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Edit your question to include your code along with your attempts of achieving the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will give you multiple value from ONE dropdown:

```
<form method="post">
    <select id="mySelectID" name="mySelectID[]" multiple>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
<pre>
<?php
var_export($_POST);
?>
</pre>
```

After a POST, you will get:

```
array (
  'mySelectID' => 
  array (
    0 => 'saab',
    1 => 'opel',
  ),
)
```

If you want to interact with other dropdown menu without reload, you need to lookat JavaScript.

**UPDATE**

A basic sample with dropdown interaction without reload
http://jsfiddle.net/hu8gf4gb/1/

Comment: Thank you. i want other drop down without reload.i am able fetch all writers in drop down list.But when i selected multiple writers in first drop down ,i am not able to write the code to get corresponding books in 2nd drop down list.Help me out please.

Comment: <div>
        <legend >&nbsp;<b>possible report types</b>&nbsp;</legend>
        <p>
                       <?php
        require_once ('inc/modeDetector.inc.php');
        getAllTheWriter();?>
   <select id="selectBook" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100% ; " onchange="getALLSelectedBook()" class="optbox">
          <option value="0">none</option>
         <?php
          require_once ('inc/modeDetector.inc.php');
                                                                                 getAllBooks()
         ?></select>
         </p>
        </fieldset> </div>